# Error installing local npm package for Cordova/Ionic Application using VS Community 2015

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use the Cordova/Ionic Template to create mobile application.
For this I am using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015.

Whenever I try to build/debug under Ripple - Nexus (Tablet) i get the following error.

> Error   BLD401  Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'.

I tried clearing the cache from Cordova Tools and building again but no success.

This is the output that I am getting in the Output Console.

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> 1>  npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac" "--loglevel" "warn"
>
> 1>  npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>
> 1>  npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>
> 1>  npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
>
> 1>  npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
>
> 1>  npm ERR!
>
> 1>RUNMDAINSTALL : npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>
> 1>  npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> 1>  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> 1>  npm ERR!     E:\Assignments\Working\Ionic Project\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\npm-debug.log
>
> 1>  ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
>
> 1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
>
> 1>  npm WARN uninstall not installed in C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules: "vs-tac"
>
> 1>  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>
> 1>  npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac" "--loglevel" "warn"
>
> 1>  npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>
> 1>  npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>
> 1>  npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
>
> 1>  npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
>
> 1>  npm ERR!
>
> 1>RUNMDAINSTALL : npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>
> 1>  npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> 1>  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> 1>  npm ERR!     E:\Assignments\Working\Ionic Project\Projects\TestProject\TestProject\npm-debug.log
>
> 1>  ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
>
> 1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
>
> 1>  npm WARN uninstall not installed in C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules: "vs-tac"

The problem seems that the npm is not able to download correctly on my machine.

Could you'll please help me to resolve this issue...

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks